# xcode developer tools and php

Tags: php, xcode, macos, mamp-pro

Can someone please explain what is the role of xcode developer tools in developing php applications and installing extensions?

Between Mamp Pro, xcode developer tools and extensions which doesn't seem to install and configure amongst the million available php.ini files, I am losing my mind.

Two days and I don't seem any step closer to running and debugging a simple app which only requires http.so.

It's insane.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is the response from MAMP PRO support.

At this point you cannot install extensions. From what I understand is header files get created when the separate versions of php are compiled. These header files are needed to compile additional extensions for that particular version/setup of php.

We had these files available in the past for some versions of MAMP PRO 2.x . We have not made them available for any versions of MAMP 3.x . We may come out with a developer edition, which will include these. I don't know when or if this is. I would open another ticket in January and see if there is any progress on this.